# how can combine different index into one index

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

I am trying to combine different index into one index.Given code is sample..

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [player_id] => 92
        [player_name] => XYZ
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [player_type_id] => 4
        [type] => All-Rounder
    ))
```

expected answer would be

```
Array([0] => stdClass Object
     ( 
      [player_id] => 92
      [player_name] => XYZ
      [player_type_id] => 4
      [type] => All-Rounder
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$objArr1 =  (array)$yourArr[0];
$objArr2 =  (array)$yourArr[1];

$mergedArr = (object)array_merge($objArr1,$objArr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive in 2 way.

1) Using `array_merge` function

2) Using `+` operator

Refer below example:

```
$obj1 = new StdClass();
$obj1->player_id = 92;
$obj1->player_name = 'Test Name';


$obj2 = new StdClass();
$obj2->player_type_id = 92;
$obj2->type = 'Test Name';

$array = array($obj1, $obj2);

$merged_array = (object) ((array) $obj1 + (array) $obj2);

print_r($merged_array);

echo '--------------------------------------- <br />';
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);

print_r($obj_merged);
```

**Output:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [player_id] => 92
    [player_name] => Test Name
    [player_type_id] => 92
    [type] => Test Name
)
--------------------------------------- 
stdClass Object
(
    [player_id] => 92
    [player_name] => Test Name
    [player_type_id] => 92
    [type] => Test Name
)
```

One more method using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($obj2 as $k => $v){
  $obj1->$k = $v;
}

print_r($obj1);
```

**Output:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [player_id] => 92
    [player_name] => Test Name
    [player_type_id] => 92
    [type] => Test Name
)
```